# Where is the Order and Export tab in Android Studio 2.x?

Tags: java, android, class, instantiation

After updating Android Studio 2.1.2 apps running on my local device now fatal errors with "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{today.trsc.songs/today.trsc.songs.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class". But the MainActivity is there in the IDE. Others with this problem suggested updating java libraries in "Order and Export" but that's an Eclipse feature; where is that in Android Studio 2.x? There is no "Properties" choice when right-clicking on Project.

Comment: I don't know what option you need, but you can try Help -> Find Action or File -> Settings or File -> Project structure

Comment: Finally just uninstalled Studio and reinstalled. Back to working again...except for emulators which have died since the 2.1 update.